# error: '_mm_prefetch' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I am now compiling a algorithm code in redhat Linux with g++4.7, but encounter some problems. The header files that one C++ file uses are bellow:

But when compiling, it occurs that some errors, such as

```
 error: '_mm_prefetch' was not declared in this scope
 error: '_MM_HINT_T0' was not declared in this scope
```

How could I solve this problem? Thank you very much!!

```
#include <cmath>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <mmintrin.h>

#include "space.h"
#include "knnquery.h"
#include "rangequery.h"
#include "ported_boost_progress.h"
#include "method/small_world_rand.h"
#include "sort_arr_bi.h"

#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>

//#define START_WITH_E0
#define START_WITH_E0_AT_QUERY_TIME

#define USE_BITSET_FOR_INDEXING 1
//#define USE_ALTERNATIVE_FOR_INDEXING 

namespace similarity {

using namespace std;

template <typename dist_t>
struct IndexThreadParamsSW {
  const Space<dist_t>&                        space_;
  SmallWorldRand<dist_t>&                     index_;
const ObjectVector& data_;
```

In this C++ file, there is a place using this codes:

```
for (MSWNode* neighbor : (currEv.getMSWNode())->getAllFriends()) {
        _mm_prefetch(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(const_cast<const Object*>(neighbor->getData())), _MM_HINT_T0);
      }
      for (MSWNode* neighbor : (currEv.getMSWNode())->getAllFriends()) {
        _mm_prefetch(const_cast<const char*>(neighbor->getData()->data()), _MM_HINT_T0);
}
```

Comment: When the compiler complaints about symbols not being declared, well, the solution seems to be rather obvious: declare them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `<xmmintrin.h>` in addition to `<mmintrin.h>`.